# (VBA) I have a for loop that searches an array for a match and it works for all but 5/68 cases. Why?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops, for-loop

There is a cell ("I3") in my worksheet that is linked to a combobox list with 68 possible values, depending on what another combobox's value was selected to be.  For one example, to keep things brief but demonstrate the problem, one possible size of the I3 combobox is 11.  There is an array called plateMC, where in this same scenario its size is also 11.  The values of the first column of the array and of the I3 combobox start at 1.8 and go up to 2.3 with increments of 0.05.  I have a For loop that runs from 1 to 11 and searches the array for a match with the cell I3.  It works for 1.8, 1.85, 2, 2.1, 2.15, 2.2, and 2.25, but not for 1.9, 2.05 or 2.3.  I have no idea why.  The data types are the same and the problem seems to lie with the plateMC array, but I have no idea where or how.  Here is the code.  (calc is the worksheet and n is 11)

```
ps = CDbl(calc.Range("I3"))
For i = 1 To n
    If ps = plateMC(i, 1) Then m = plateMC(i, 2)
Next i
```

Instead of setting m equal to what the array value is, it goes to 0 for all the numbers I listed above that don't work.  I have no idea why.  Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: I recommend examining the values in debug mode, or do a debug.print to get the values in the immediate screen. Do something like debug.print FORMAT(ps, "###,###,##0.00000000"). I think you'll find there's some mathematical inaccuracies that you might have to use the ROUND function to correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing Doubles when Singles would be sufficient. Comparing as Doubles incurs more bits to represent the number, and comparisons for equivalence can fail due to this increased precision. If you create an array of Singles and compare them to "I3" as a `Single` by using `ps = CSng(calc.Range("I3"))` you should 'find' all your values.  The test code below does not pop-up any message boxes when the three test values are Doubles (test1 => test3).  But, when they are Singles (test4 => test6), you get three message box pop-ups.

```
        Sub ArrayTest()

'Create a Collection to simulate plateMC array
            Dim vals As Collection
            Set vals = New Collection
            Dim n As Integer
            n = 11

            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 1 To n
                vals.Add 1.8 + (i - 1) * 0.05
            Next i

    'Test As Double compared to Singles
            Dim test1, test2, test3 As Double
            test1 = CDbl(1.9)
            test2 = CDbl(2.05)
            test3 = CDbl(2.3)
            For i = 1 To n
                If test1 = vals.Item(i) Then
                    MsgBox CStr(test1) + " as Double Found!"
                End If
                If test2 = vals.Item(i) Then
                    MsgBox CStr(test2) + "as Double Found!"
                End If
                If test3 = vals.Item(i) Then
                    MsgBox CStr(test3) + "as Double Found!"
                End If
            Next i

    'Test As Single compared to Singles

            Dim test4, test5, test6 As Single
            test4 = CSng(1.9)
            test5 = CSng(2.05)
            test6 = CSng(2.3)
            For i = 1 To n
                If test4 = vals.Item(i) Then
                    MsgBox CStr(test4) + " as Single Found!"
                End If
                If test5 = vals.Item(i) Then
                    MsgBox CStr(test5) + " as Single Found!"
                End If
                If test6 = vals.Item(i) Then
                    MsgBox CStr(test6) + " as Single Found!"
                End If
            Next i

        End Sub
```

Comment: Okay so I can confirm the issue is with the plateMC array. Earlier in the code i populated it with a for loop where the repeated code was plateMC(i,1) = 1.8 + (i-1) * 0.05  .  In the locals window, it says the array is filled exactly like it should be.  But that was not working so I decided to explicitly define the entries that weren't working (plateMC(3,1) & (6,1) & (11,1)) and then the problem was fixed.  I don't know why this worked and would like to fix it the "right way."  But hey if this is the only thing that works, then I guess this is the right way haha.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. Can you explain why the equation defaulted to creating Singles when I dimmed the array as a Double?

Comment: I am unable to find a definitive answer.  In general comparing floating point numbers for equality can be an issue (if you rely on the `=` operator. [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/troubleshooting-data-types) may be useful to you.

Comment: My comment above that the array defaulted to Singles was incorrect.  If you dimmed your array as Double, then your array is filled with Doubles.  The Double to Double comparison for equivalence simply fails due to the Double representation of the generated values being 'slightly' different.  Explicitly using Singles, in this scenario, removes enough precision from the generated values that the equivalence comparison succeeds the way you want.